# Chrome input[type=date] keyboard entry

Tags: html, google-chrome, date

I really like the way that Chrome (and Opera) supports the `input[type=date]` with the built in datepicker but it seems most people visiting my site type in the date by hand rather than using the datepicker. This is supported fully but when they do not type fast enough, the field interprets the entry as new.

Example: You try to enter a date of birth `mm/dd/yyyy`. On the month and day there are usually no problems but when it comes to the year, on entering 1986, with just a slight pause in the middle you end up with 0086.

Question: Is there a way to extend the allowed pause time before it resets? It's just a fraction to short for my customers.

Comment: Could you try using the attribute: autocomplete="off"? http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.autocomplete

Comment: Unfortunately autocomplete="off" does nothing, but thanks for trying

Comment: AFAIK, there are no ways to control it.  Please add stars to http://crbug.com/232296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fortunately this was fixed in Chrome and Opera

Comment: Can you share the reference? It is still failing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with int32_t ( comment ), and IMHO, you're better off just implementing a jquery or other plugin as default to help you with date input... Three reasons for this approach:

1. Contrary to the HTML5 datepickers, that aren't themable, jquery ui datepickers are. This could provide your users with a uniform user experience where otherwise it would be different on different browsers. It will also be easier to test since these should work the same on almost every browser. I'm not saying you shouldn't test on other browsers, but there should be less pain... :)
2. If you want to make sure most users are happy, you probably will end up writing fallback mechanisms... And as long as you have to provide the fallback, I don't see a lot of reasons not to use this fallback as default since they work in more cases than the HTML5 ones ...
3. Libraries like JQuery are written for a uniform approach across browsers. They abstract issues so you should not think about different browsers using a different approach for straight-forward stuff like events or user input. Hence, they are in a position to decide wether to use the HTML5 input or not...

I know this does not answer your question, but it was to long to write in the comments... :)

Comment: You're right, this is not an answer. I do appreciate your honest opinion, but I disagree. Yes, we do have a fallback js datepicker for those browsers that do not support HTML5 input[type=date] but we don't want our mobile visitors to be confronted with this when their browser is perfectly capable of showing them the device's default datpicker.

Comment: wow, I actually wasn't thinking about mobile users, but you have a valid point ... Which fallback datepicker are you using if I may ask?